# Assigning values to const int in headerfile in c++ without initialization list

Tags: c++, header, integer, constants, initialization-list

I got 17 integer constants that I'd like to have as private in my class. Is it really necessary to use initialization list?

I read somewhere that I can assign values to constants in the header file, but it doesn't seem to work. I get this error message:

```
sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers
```

Comment: It is a must... object which is declared as a const, cant' be assigned, it can only be initialized.

Comment: If they're private, and they're constant ... why couple them to the header at all? Just put them in an anonymous namespace in your .cpp file as `static const int`s. Unless, of course, you need access to them in inlined methods.

Comment: I need access to them in inlined methods!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it really necessary to use initialization list?

In modern (2011-era) C++, no. In older versions of the language, yes.

Your error message is apologising that your compiler doesn't support the new initialisation syntax for non-static members yet. Assuming you're using GCC (since I recognise that error from that compiler), then according to [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) you'll need to upgrade to at least version 4.7 for that feature.

Alternatively, since they're private and constant, you might consider moving them out of the class into a local namespace in the class's implementation file. Of course, that will only work if you don't need to access them from any inline member functions.

Finally, if they have the same values for all instances of the class (which is likely, since they are `const` and you're able initialise them independently of the constructor arguments), you could declare them `static`. Then they can be initialised in their declaration (although older compilers might only allow that if they have an integer type). However, if they are *odr-used* (roughly speaking, if you need to take a pointer or reference to them), then they will also need to be defined in exactly one source file.

Answer (score 0):

.h:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();

        int doSomething();

    private:
        const int m_newint = 1;
        const int m_dosomething = 2;
};
```

.cc:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {}
MyClass::~MyClass() {}

int MyClass::doSomething() {
    return m_dosomething;
}
```

Is valid C++11 code, make sure your compiler is set to `-std=c++11` to use the
feature.

Comment: @MooingDuck Adding const in front of the variable doesn't change anything.

Comment: But it means they're effectively if not actually static, and that means it's trivial (and better!) to solve this problem in a C++03 compatible way.

Comment: @MooingDuck: But if they are static you have to use the full class name each time you want to use them, something that is not the case with non-static members. Also constant members in a class are not exported by the linker IIRC.

Comment: [GCC and MSVC beg to differ](http://ideone.com/DrBOcu).  Heck, even `enum` is a better idea than wasting all that spac.